# How to use multiple Custom Cascades in OpenCV Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, object-detection, object-recognition

I am using CV2 for Custom Model Detections. Can anyone tell me how to use multiple custom models in one Program?

Suppose in Fruit Detection and Recognition System, if I made custom cascades of Banana, Apple, and Oranges. Now, how I gonna use these three cascades in one Program, or if there is any other way kindly inform me. Thanks

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/how-to-use-multiple-custom-cascades/2005

Answer (score 1):

This will help you to use multiple `CascadeClassifier` in one program.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

banana_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('path to Banana.xml')
apple_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('path to Apple.xml')
oranges_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('path to Oranges.xml')

device = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    
    ret, frame = device.read()
    if ret:
        
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        banana = banana_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 10)
        apple = apple_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 10)
        oranges = oranges_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 10)

        for (x, y, w, h) in banana + apple + oranges:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)

        cv2.imshow("fruit detected", frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0XFF == ord('q'):
            break

device.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: @Vatsak Parsaniya, Detection is good. It is detecting but the issue comes with recognizing plants and writing names on them. Can you modify the code or tell me how to recognize plants and write names on them?

Comment: You can check `cv2.putText` method. You already have x,y coordinates where you can write names.

Comment: Thanks, But coordinates can be of more than one Fruit, and then how to identify that these two coordinates are of one fruit and the other two coordinates are of one and some fruits had no Coordinates.